# sms_autofill.dart:73:31: Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const'

Tags: sms, autofill

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
? Loading configs from configs/env.props...
? Copying configs/google-services.json to android/app/google-services.json
? Copying configs/customized to project...

?  Building HDH... ?

? Signing with keystore key.jks... ?

/C:/Users/ROY/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sms_autofill-2.2.0/lib/sms_autofill.dart:73:31: Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.
this.decoration = const UnderlineDecoration(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

ended up with this error try to delete cache ,did clean and all the commands and populate new dependencies but still ending up with this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Found that a new version of sms_autofill was released 3 days ago (2.3.0). Update the version in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
sms_autofill: 2.3.0
```